# How can I retrieve the value of the whole selected object in MenuItems?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, zod

In my dropdown, I need to show the ll.llIDs, which is working nicely. However, once an item is selected, I need to know the ll._id of the selected object. I have this dropdown within a form, so when the user selects all the form's details, I need to send this to the backend. I can't just send a llID to the backend, I need to send the id instead.

`<TextField
id="ll-id"
select
label="LL-ID"
defaultValue={row ? row.original.landlord.llID : ""}

```
      {...register("landlord")}
    >
      {landlords.map((ll) => (
        <MenuItem key={ll._id} value={ll.llID}>
          {ll.llID}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>`
```

I tried to add the ll object in the value field, but it doesn't work because it only accepts primitive values.

Comment: which one is the name of the id object do you want to return? What does the `MenuItem` component do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Solved
I did the following to solve this problem if anyone needs it:

````
 <TextField
            id="ll-id"
            select
            label="LL-ID"
            defaultValue={row ? row.original.landlord?._id : ""}
            {...register("landlord._id")}
          >
            <MenuItem value=""></MenuItem>
            {landlords.map((ll) => (
              <MenuItem key={ll._id} value={ll._id}>
                {ll.llID}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </TextField>
    ```
````